# Eclipse launch error- error code 13

Tags: java, eclipse, launch, ini

Eclipse returns this error message when launching:

[image: error message]
I am pretty sure that both the java installation and Eclipse are both for my 64-bit system.

Here is my .ini file:

[image: ini file]

Comment: Now that you have 11 rep, you could edit your post so that the images are included in the post rather than as links

Comment: Adding details as images on external sites is never a good idea, directly attach images here or better yet copy the appropriate information and paste in your question.

Comment: SO, now that I've posted the pics, any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Eclipse looks OK, based on the filename.

To check your version of Java, run java -version in a console. On Windows 7 with 64-bit Java 6 I get:

java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)

Check that this is the version being used by Eclipse, as shown in your error code. If not, call that version explicitly, e.g.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -version

Comment: I have seen this exact thing on another post-it didn't help then, and it doesn't help now. I very much appreciate the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the
-vm

up below the first openfile, not the second.

PIC:
[image: the solved .ini file!]